# Can an external force be a conservative force or all external force non conservative?

Tags: energy-conservation

Given a system, all existing internal forces are such that the net internal force is always zero. An internal force can be either conservative or nonconservative. If the internal forces are all conservative and the net external force is zero, both the system mechanical energy ME and total energy E are conserved. However, if there is one or more internal nonconservative force, ME is not conserved but the total energy E remains conserved.
When there are nonzero external forces, I believe that any external force can only be nonconservative. To start, a net nonzero external force changes the total energy E of the system (only if it displaces the system). If the net external force was conservative, there would be a potential energy function between a component internal to the system and an entity external to the system.
Wouldn't a potential energy function between a component internal to the system and something in the environment be a problem? In general, I tend to think that a potential energy function can only be defined for the system alone: it represents energy stored in the the spatial configuration of the internal components of the system. I don't see how a potential energy can exist btw the system and something outside of it in the environment...

Answer (score 1):

Internal forces, such like friction, can be nonconservative. External forces, such as gravity (if your system does not include the entire earth), can be conservative. Your beliefs are inaccurate.

Comment: Ok, in the case of a rock and Earth, if the system is only the rock, the gravity becomes an external force and is also conservative. As gravity pulls the rock downward, the gravitational potential energy of the system decreases. But the system is only the rock so it cannot have potential energy by itself. The potential energy would be shared between the system and something external to the system (earth) in the environment...

Comment: yes, in that description, the rock has potential energy by itself, due to the gravitational field that permeates the space. The origin of that field is irrelevant.